# Multiple Datasources in DataGrid (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I wonder if we can implement and fetch data from different datasources into a DataGrid.
Let's say for example i have a 3 stored procedures:

What I did is drag 3 datasources and configured it in each stored procedures.

1st stored procedures : returns @id and @name
2nd stored procedures : returns @name, @server and @location
3rd stored procedures : returns @age and @years

and I want only to show @id from 1st SPROC, @server from 2nd SRPOC and @age from 3rd SPROC, and bind it to one DataGrid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set several datasources on any control.

Why not create a stored procedure that retrieves all the information you want in one go? Then you can bind the result to your DataGrid.

Comment: Well I think I should tell the DBA who made those sprocs to do your suggestion hehe, i wonder why he doesn't have an idea if I could get those data from his sprocs that he threw to me :), anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Oded. Having one source makes it simple and easy to manage/debug. But if you prefer to have multiplet data sources, I would populate a dataset with these data sources, generate a dataview from this dataset (selecting the appropriate data) and bind the view to the datagrid. An example from [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-ADONET-DataGrid-Multiple-Tables)

```
private void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "server=P-III; database=programmersheaven;" +
                      "uid=sa; pwd=;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM article";
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "article");
    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM author";
    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, conn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "author");
    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ArtAuth", 
            ds.Tables["author"].Columns["authorId"], 
            ds.Tables["article"].Columns["authorId"] 
            );
    ds.Relations.Add(relation);
    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["author"]);
    dgDetails.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, I will try to implement this one! Now I can sleep deeply without thinking what to do in this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an inner join query in the `sqldatasource` at the `selectcommand` property to select what you want from the DB, then access the `datagrid.datasourceID` from the `sqldatasource` control.